# Fragment not displaying pre-Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-fragments

When using the [recommended code][1] to start a fragment at launch, it displays properly on a virtual device running Android 5.0 but doesn't display on a phone running 4.4.2.

I've created the activity using mostly auto generated code from Android Studio.

The *Toast* in the fragment gets activated on the phone, so I know the fragment is being started. It's just not being displayed on the phone for some reason.

Any help getting it to run would be appreciated.

Here's the Activity code:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks, UserOverviewFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private static final String PREF_FIRST_RUN = "false";

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        // TODO: get this working.
        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            UserOverviewFragment firstFragment = new UserOverviewFragment();



            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
//            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, firstFragment).commit();
        }


        // TODO: Do something the first time the app is started.


        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO: invalidate menu as soon as the drawer slides a certain amount
        if(mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }else
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }




    public void changeMainFragment(){

    }

    public boolean checkForFirstRun(){
        String firstRun = mNavigationDrawerFragment.readSharedSetting(getBaseContext(), PREF_FIRST_RUN, "true");
        if(firstRun == "true"){
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.saveSharedSetting(getBaseContext(), PREF_FIRST_RUN, "false");
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public void onFirstRun(){
        // TODO: Stuff to do just once, the first time the app is run. Possibly not necessary.


        // TODO: Delete this next line after testing.
        Toast.makeText(this, "First Time!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void determineStartingFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.king_kingdom.mathiness.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link UserOverviewFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link UserOverviewFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class UserOverviewFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment user_overview.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static UserOverviewFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        UserOverviewFragment fragment = new UserOverviewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public UserOverviewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"This is the User Overview Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_overview, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.king_kingdom.mathiness.UserOverviewFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Overview"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="109dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE: Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.king_kingdom.toolbar_test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: I never used NavigationDrawer. However I know that supporting ActionBarActivity for both Android 5 (API 21) and pre-API 21 is tricky. So you need to see the build.gradle file and check for the compile dependency and the SDK versions. So just upload that file for analysis.

Comment: Added the gradle build file. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was a simple problem of styling. In my style code, I had accidentally assigned both the background and the text color as white. Which means, of course, that you couldn't see it.

I'm not quite sure why it was showing in the emulator except that there was possibly a default style in API v21 that skirted my app.theme.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @papium for uploading the **build.gradle**. For now, I would suggest changing in that file:
**From**: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

**To**: `compile ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**18.0.0**`

However this impacts the API 21 and future Android versions. Another, maybe you can see the NavigationDrawer but not your ActionBar.